# If x > 100 then fun : x – 10; Else fun : fun(fun (x + 11))

Tags: language-agnostic

I've been preparing for competitive exam and I came across this question. I tried writing the code for it. But I didn't got the answer according to the options given. The output I got was time out.
 Please help me find the correct answer

What value would the following function return for the input x = 95?

```
 Function fun (x:integer):integer;
 Begin
 If x > 100 then fun : x – 10
 Else fun : fun(fun (x + 11))
 End;
```

And the options are
(a) 89 (b) 90 (c) 91 (d) 92

Comment: In which programming language have you written your example? Please add this tag to your post.

Comment: If I work it out mentally I get 91.

Comment: you can try it in any program language @reporter

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I made this of it in JAVA:

```
 public static int test(int x){

     if (x > 100){
         return x-10;
     }// then fun : x – 10
     else {
         return test(test(x+11));
     }//fun : fun(fun (x + 11))
     }

 System.out.println(test(95));
```

the result was:

> 91

.

Answer (score 2):

The equivalent of your program in c++

```
#include <cstdio>

int fun(int x)
{
    if (x > 100)
    {
        return x-10;
    }
    else
    {
        return fun(fun(x+11));
    }
}

int main()
{
    printf("%i", fun(95));
    return 0;
}
```

Outputs:

```
91
```

Although you could've easily figured out the answer at the line "if x > 100 then return x-10". If you feed it any number under 100 its always going to output 91. If you change it to "if x >= 100 then return x-10" and you feed it with any number under 100 its always going to return 90.

Answer (score 0):

I ran your answer in python with following code , the answer was 91:

```
    def fun(x):
        if(x >100):
            return x-10
        else:
            return fun(fun(x+11))

    print (fun(95))
```